# Is there any specific time to do push-ups

Tags: push-ups

I have started doing push-up at home, after discontinuing from the regular gym. But, these days, I am leaving home early in the morning at 7:00 AM for work, I couldn't find time for push-ups in the morning. So, I just want to ask if its okay to do push-ups in the night at 8:30 PM?

Is it a mandate kinda thing that it must be done in the morning only. Or is it a common myth? I have seen some Fitness centers around, which display : "Open in morning: 5-9 AM and Evening:6-9 PM" on their shop boards. And, In some of the movies that I have seen, actors does push-ups at work or whenever they feel like, this may be a bad example.

Can I do push-ups at night?

Comment: sure, if you can do. As stated in oliver's answer, doing compound and large muscle (chest, lats, thighs) will be more beneficial as compared to only push-ups (that only involves pecs, triceps, and shoulders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can workout any time in the day. But it is best before eating.

During night you can be tired too. Found the moment it is best for you when you have no stress and ready to have a good workout.

Additionally, push-ups is a really good exercise but try to do some pull exercises (pull-ups, Australian pull-ups ...)  and legs exercices (squat, lunge ...)